# extjs grid reserveScrollbar with layout 'absolute'

Tags: extjs, extjs-grid

version : extjs-5.0

ExtJs `grid` has a property `reserveScrollbar` which reserves space for scroll bar. I've a `window` with `layout : 'absolute'` which is the container for `grid`.

Now the problem is, the `grid` doesn't reserve space for scroll bar. Many forum say the container  should use `layout:'fit'` to make it work. However I want it to be `layout : 'absolute'` only.

I set exact width and height for the grid and for its columns. I expect grid to reserve space from its width.(Leaving this to Sencha).

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: absolute will create problems when app is running at differnet resolutions still it is fine for you ?

Comment: Yes it is fine. The grid is in a window with fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the grid inside a container or panel that has `layout: 'fit'`.  The container can then be within a window that has `layout: 'absolute'`.  You can then set the height and width for the container instead of the grid.

See example [fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r7q).